# Jqgrid having trouble loading all data from the server using loadonce

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, jqgrid, asp.net-web-api

so I have a grid that uses loadonce set to true and rowTotal to spicify the number of rows returned. My database has about 200,000 records, however it seems to timeout if I set the return to that amount, I can only really load about 20,000 records without any problems. Is there a way to make it return everything from the database? My query I use to retrieve the values is

```
public IEnumerable<vwWell> GetAll()
    {

        return from e in db.vwWells
               select e;
    }
```

my web API code is

```
static readonly IWellRepository repository = new WellRepository();

    WellsMigrationEntities db = new WellsMigrationEntities();


    // GET api/values
   public dynamic Get(string sidx, string sord, int page, int totalrows)
    {
        var wells = repository.GetAll() as IEnumerable<vwWell>;
        var pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        var pageSize = totalrows;
        var totalRecords = wells.Count();
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
        wells = wells.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalrows,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = wells.ToArray() //We need an array of objects for the rows
        };
        return jsonData;
  }
```

and my grid code is

```
<script>

var API_URL = "http://localhost:41389/api/well";
jQuery("#gridMain").jqGrid({
    url: API_URL,
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'GET',
    loadonce: true,
    gridview: true,
    autowidth: true,
    sortable: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    colNames: ['Id', 'APINumber', 'CountyName', 'LeaseName'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'WellKey', index: 'WellKey', width: 55, sorttype: "int", hidden: true},
        { name: 'APINumber', index: 'APINumber', width: 90, sorttype: "text" },
        { name: 'CountyName', index: 'CountyName', width: 100, sorttype: "text" },
        { name: 'LeaseName', index: 'LeaseName', width: 80, sorttype: "text" }
    ],
    pager: '#pager3',
    rowNum: 200,
    rowTotal: 20000,
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "WellKey" },
    rowList: [200, 300, 500],
    sortname: 'WellKey',
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "JSON Example"

});
```

See how I have rowTotal set to 20,000, if I dont set that nothing returns, but it seems I am limited in the number of rows it is able to return.

Comment: The browser is going to go crazy trying to load that much data into the DOM. Don't do it.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, what do you suggest I do? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: use jqgrid's paging options to just load one page at a time.

Comment: Well paging is setup right now, well I think at least. With 20k records and 200 rows per page, I have about 100 pages. Is there a special way to do the paging? I want to load all the records and page them

Comment: The jQgrid documentation shows how to do the paging. jQgrid sends parameters to the server with the current page number and page size, and the server should then convert these to the `LIMIT` clause in the query.